# Can I add an existing table column to a transactional replication without requiring a full snapshot?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a large table that participates in a transactional replication.  However, only some of the columns are replicated and I need to add an existing source column into the replication.  I can add the column to the target table and as a one off exercise fill the data into it myself.  However if I edit the replication it wants to take a new snapshot.  I'd like to avoid this due to the time that it takes and the fact we index the table differently in the target database and I'd like to avoid rebuilding all of the indexes.

Is this possible or am I wasting my time trying to find the solution?